# The named parameter 'progressIndicatorColor' isn't defined

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

i get error when i use

```
progressIndicatorColor: Color(0xFFB71C1C),
                          showRecentsTab: true,
                          recentsLimit: 28,
                          noRecentsText: "No Recents",
                          noRecentsStyle: const TextStyle(
```

i use

```
import 'package:emoji_picker_flutter/emoji_picker_flutter.dart';
```

and i get this error

Comment: check out this https://pub.dev/documentation/emoji_picker_flutter/1.6.3/ . You can use other color parameters instead of progressIndicatorColor .

Comment: It is removed and updated  in latest version .

Answer (score 2):

There is no `progressIndicatorColor`. You can use

- `indicatorColor`
- `skinToneIndicatorColor`

More about [emoji_picker_flutter/1.6.3/](https://pub.dev/documentation/emoji_picker_flutter/1.6.3/)

Comment: thx i really appreciate